# Browser not maintaining correct history in React Application

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am going in between pages in React Application, but on going back in the browser it skip some pages. Not taking to the right page when doing back. I am handling routing in my application like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/dir/page1/" exact component={page1} />
      <Route path="/dir/page1" exact component={page2} />
      <Route path="/dir/page3" exact component={page3} />
      <Route path="/dir/:query" exact component={page4} />
      <Route path="/faq/" exact component={Faq} />
      <Route path="/about/" exact component={AboutUs} />
      <Route path="/terms/" exact component={Terms} />
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

How can i make my browser to follow correct back history and not skipping pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `window.location.replace(url);` which was making it skip the page in the history. I changed it with `window.location.href = url;`